# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null (Ionic Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

In my angular ionic project, when I log in the first page gives me the error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null" but when I reload the page I don't have the error and I have the data. thank you

````
    (await this.pageService.getAllTables()).subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.tables = res.body
    });
  }```

    ```getAllTables() {
        this.storage.get('USER').then(user =>{this.user = user;});
        return this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then(token =>{
            if (this.user) {
                return this.http.get(this.url + 'table/' + this.user.id, { 
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    }), 
                    observe: 'response'
                });
            }
            return null;
        });
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
getAllTables() {
        return this.storage.get('USER')
           .then(user =>{this.user = user;})
           .then(() => this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN'))
           .then(token =>{
             if (this.user) {
                return this.http.get(this.url + 'table/' + this.user.id, { 
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    }), 
                    observe: 'response'
                });
            }
            return null;
        });
```

this code is still strange, as you return observable, wrapped in promise but at least is should work.

you could try to convert everything to promises. it would look like this:

```
getAllTables() {
        return this.storage.get('USER')
           .then(user =>{this.user = user;})
           .then(() => this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN'))
           .then(token =>{
             if (this.user) {
                return this.http.get(this.url + 'table/' + this.user.id, { 
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    }), 
                    observe: 'response'
                }).toPromise();
            }
            return null;
        });
```

usage:

```
this.tables = (await this.pageService.getAllTables())?.body;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I no longer have the error, however my front-end data does not appear until I have reloaded the page

Answer (score 0):

i think your this.pageService.getAllTables is not loaded yet when you subscribe.

please first inject the "pageService" in constructor and then convert everything to promises

**like This**

```
constructor(){
private pageService: PageService

}
```

**after that convert everything to promises**

```
getAllTables() {
    return this.storage.get('USER')
       .then(user =>{this.user = user;})
       .then(() => this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN'))
       .then(token =>{
         if (this.user) {
            return this.http.get(this.url + 'table/' + this.user.id, { 
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                }), 
                observe: 'response'
            }).toPromise();
        }
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I no longer have the error, however my front-end data does not appear until I have reloaded the page. 
But I already had the declaration in my constructor.